# Is it possible for Eclipse to also import dependent projects when I import my master project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a master project that depends on two other library projects. Both of the dependent projects are nested in my master project's directory structure. I would like to configure the project so that when I import it into Eclipse (Import > Existing projects into workspace) I also import the dependent projects.

My question is, is it possible to configure Eclipse to import dependent projects whenever I import the master project?

Answer (score 0):

If they are dependent through a maven pom.xml , you can import the dependent modules in that structure by importing "Existing Maven Projects"

Comment: Maven (build system) seems a little overkill considering all I want to do is import dependent projects. I am hoping there is a more light weight approach.

Answer (score 0):

If those projects are version controlled, you can create a [project set file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PSF) to import/export them as a group. This works with all the major version control systems in Eclipse, if you install their respective project set support feature.

Comment: <edit> - deleted my last comment as it was meant for a different answer.